# unexpected mysql error saying must be an instance of mysqli_result?

Tags: php, mysql

Ugh, got this unexpected error:

```
Argument 1 passed to QMySqliDatabaseResult::__construct() must be an instance of mysqli_result, boolean given, called in /home/aptana/domains/staging-allyforce.aptanacloud.com/web/htdocs/includes/qcodo/_core/database/QMySqli5Database.class.php on line 52 and defined
Error Type:   Unknown
```

I'm not sure what happened, it worked fine earlier, still trying to figure out how to reproduce.

```
Line 420:           public function __construct(mysqli_result $objResult, QMySqliDatabase $objDb) {
Line 421:               $this->objMySqliResult = $objResult;
Line 422:               $this->objDb = $objDb;
Line 423:           }
```

Comment: The calling code is at fault. Try line 52 of `home/aptana/domains/staging-allyforce.aptanacloud.com/web/htdocs/includes/qcodo/_core/database/QMySqli5Database.class.php`. Note that `mysqli::query` returns `false` on error, so that could be the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks pretty plain in the error message.  You're constructing an object and passing it a boolean value instead of a mysqli_result object.  This violates the type, so you're [getting a type hinting error](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php).  (My guess is you're getting a mysqli_result object from somewhere, assigning it to a boolean variable, then passing that variable in to the constructor.)

Can you show the line where you construct the object, causing the error to be thrown?

Comment: Yeah, that's what's confusing because not sure why it would be assigning a boolean variable.  Hunting it down....